# Can we use SUM and Max Function with each other in SQL Statement?

Tags: sql

i have following requirements :

```
CODE         Marks  
A             50  
A             50  

B             60  
B             60  

C             20  
C             20
```

Now , i want to write a query to display the CODE and Marks of top scorer. In this example its B and 120. how to write it in SQL.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question and add some example inputs/outputs? It is very hard to understand what you are asking. Also, please specify which database you are using.

Answer (score 6):

Standard SQL

```
SELECT 
   Code, MAX(SumMarks)
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
       SUM(Marks) as SumMarks, Code
    FROM
       SomeTable
    GROUP BY
       Code
    ) foo
GROUP BY
   Code
```

Using TOP or LIMIT (uncomment as needed). For SQL Server, this is preferable (using WITH TIES) because you may have another SUM of scores with the same maximum value

```
SELECT -- TOP 1 -- WITH TIES if you have 2 scores the same
   SUM(Marks) as SumMarks, Code
FROM
   SomeTable
GROUP BY
   Code
ORDER BY
   SUM(Marks) DESC
-- LIMIT 1
```

If not what you need, it should inspire you at least...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want only a single row containing the code with the highest aggregate score, this query should do the trick... (assuming MS SQL)

```
   SELECT TOP 1 Code, SCORE
    FROM 
      (SELECT Code, SUM(Marks) as score FROM YourTable GROUP BY Code)
    ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL or MySQL:

```
SELECT code
     , marks
  FROM (
     SELECT CODE
          , sum(Marks) as marks
       FROM yourtable
   GROUP BY CODE
   ORDER BY 2 DESC
 ) mysums
 LIMIT 1
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1
       code
     , marks
  FROM (
     SELECT CODE
          , sum(Marks) as marks
       FROM yourtable
   GROUP BY CODE
   ORDER BY 2 DESC
 ) mysums
```