# Max() function not working with Sum()

Tags: function, subquery, aggregate

The query(edited format):

```
SELECT 
    league_id as League, TeamId, MAX(TotalGoals) as Goals,season
FROM
    (SELECT 
        league_id, TeamId, SUM(TeamGoals) AS TotalGoals, season
FROM
    (SELECT 
    league_id,
        season ,
        home_team_api_id AS TeamId,
        SUM(home_team_goal) AS TeamGoals
FROM
    games
GROUP BY TeamId , league_id , season UNION SELECT 
    league_id,
        season,
        away_team_api_id AS TeamId,
        SUM(away_team_goal) AS TeamGoals
FROM
    games
GROUP BY TeamId , league_id , season) t1
GROUP BY TeamId , season) g3
GROUP BY league_id , season;
```

I am getting wrong answer for Max().Please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Refer the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759347/can-we-use-sum-and-max-function-with-each-other-in-sql-statement

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to share your SQL table as well?

I guessed you said you got a wrong answer with MAX() it is because the source of MAX() is from a SUM().

You applied MAX(TotalGoals) as Goals, but, also SUM(TeamGoals) AS TotalGoals,
obviously, TotalGoals is a result of SUM(TeamGoals) and the MAX() func will become ===> MAX( SUM(TeamGoals) ), which will surely returns the same result of the SUM().

Well, looking forwards to other developers who could share their point of views....

I copied you SQL and format it in a SQL beautifier in below:

```
SELECT
   league_id as League,
   TeamId,
   MAX(TotalGoals) as Goals,
   season 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         league_id,
         TeamId,
         SUM(TeamGoals) AS TotalGoals,
         season 
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               league_id,
               season,
               home_team_api_id AS TeamId,
               SUM(home_team_goal) AS TeamGoals 
            FROM
               games 
            GROUP BY
               TeamId,
               league_id,
               season 
            UNION
            SELECT
               league_id,
               season,
               away_team_api_id AS TeamId,
               SUM(away_team_goal) AS TeamGoals 
            FROM
               games 
            GROUP BY
               TeamId,
               league_id,
               season
         )
         t1 
      GROUP BY
         TeamId,
         season
   )
   g3 
GROUP BY
   league_id,
   season;
```